Involution of 3-sphere

Suppose that a closed geodesic $\gamma$ is the fixed-point set of an isometric involution on $(\mathbb{S}^3,g)$. Assume that sectional curvature of $g$ is at least $1$.
Is it true that $$\mathrm{length}\,\gamma\leqslant2\cdot\pi\ ?$$

Comments.

The same question can be asked about polyhedral metrics on $\mathbb{S}^3$ with curvature at least 1 in the sense of Alexandrov.

If instead of an isometric involution we have an $\mathbb{S}^1$-action, then the answer is yes.
It follows since the quotient space $(\mathbb{S}^3,g)/\mathbb{S}^1$ is a convex disc with  curvature at least 1 in the sense of Alexandrov,
and $\gamma$ projects isometrically to its boundary.

If we go one dimesion up, that is consider involution of $(\mathbb{S}^4,g)$ with fixed 2-sphere, then the fixed sphere has sectional curvature at least 1; therefore, its area cannot exceed the area of $\mathbb{S}^2$.



Why cannot we suspend the involution? Its fixed point set is then the suspension on the given circle. Doesn't an area bound on the 2d suspension gives a bound on the length of the equator?

This is naive, but can you take the spherical warped product and apply the 4D case?

@IgorBelegradek and IanAgol: the spherical suspension, say $\Sigma^4$ in an Alexandrov space with curvature $\ge 1$ and it is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^4$. It is expected that the fixed point set of codimension 2 in  $\Sigma^4$ is an Alexandrov space with curvature $\ge 1$, but it is unknown. If the codimension $\ge 3$ then there are counterexamples. (By the way codimesion 1 case is equivalent to the conjecture that boundary of Alexandrov space is an Alexandrov space.)
